# how to parse json into rows instead of columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a table from a JSON object. The table has a structure like

[image]

In this table, each quote would be the new single row with the quote key as the value for the column ABBR.

Based on the examples I found, I was able to do below, but now I am stuck on how to update the table there. It creates a new column for each quote key.

```
DECLARE @fx_rates_json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @fx_rates_json = N'{
    "date": "2019-12-02",
    "quotes": {
        "USDARS": 3.673197,
        "USDAUD": 78.79768,
        "USDBGN": 110.795056
    }
}'

SELECT jsonpayload.*
FROM OPENJSON (@fx_rates_json, N'$')
  WITH (
    Date DATETIME N'$.date',
    ARS float N'$.quotes.USDARS',
    AUD float N'$.quotes.USDAUD',
    BGN float N'$.quotes.USDBGN'
  ) AS jsonpayload
```

Comment: What what are your expected results here? Also, what you have given us doesn't appear to work: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=db1a6b1b4f36546fba3d881d7ee09b7b).

Comment: its like this guys, just remove the ... and the comma at the end. , let me update it to working. the payload is far bigger.

Comment: now it should work as i removed the ...

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue, @TheFool , like I showed you in the fiddle...

Comment: because you need to remove the semicolons as well if you dont use ssms. the variable is not declared anymore after semicolon

Comment: ... look at the fiddle, @TheFool. `;` is a statement terminator, not a batch terminator. A variable persists for an **entire** batch, not a single statement (they would be useless if is was the latter). Either way, I've posted by answer, even without expected results.

Comment: it works here @Larnu http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7863f and in ssms as well. I let you guys know which answer worked. Cannot test right now.

Comment: The problem you have with example is that `USDARS` doesn't exist in your sample data, @TheFool .

Comment: no, like i say, JSON payload is 160+ items and the table contains 41 of them. Key is there in the payload.  Just change the name if you want to see some value. The point is i need rows and not columns. You guys gave good examples, I think one or more of them will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you want to parse this JSON input and get result as rows, the next statement may help. You need to use `OPENJSON()` with default schema (without the `WITH` clause). In this case the result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @fx_rates_json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @fx_rates_json = N'{
    "date": "2019-12-02",
    "quotes": {
        "USDAED": 3.673197,
        "USDAFN": 78.79768,
        "USDALL": 110.795056
    }
}';
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   REPLACE(jsonpayload.[key], N'USD', N'') AS ABBREVIATION,
   jsonpayload.[value] AS CONVERSION,
   JSON_VALUE(@fx_rates_json, N'$.date') AS [DATE]
FROM OPENJSON (@fx_rates_json, N'$.quotes') jsonpayload
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------------
ABBREVIATION    CONVERSION  DATE
--------------------------------------
AED             3.673197    2019-12-02
AFN             78.79768    2019-12-02
ALL             110.795056  2019-12-02
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`s in an `update`:

```
update t
    set conversion = v.value
from toupdate t cross join
     openjson (@fx_rates_json, N'$')
     with (Date DATETIME N'$.date',
           ARS float N'$.quotes.USDARS',
           AUD float N'$.quotes.USDAUD',
           BGN float N'$.quotes.USDBGN',
     ) j cross apply
     (values ('ARS', j.ARS), ('AUD', j.AUD), ('BGN', j.BGN)
     ) v(abbreviation, value)
where t.abbreviation = v.abbrevation
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you are after is this:

```
DECLARE @fx_rates_json nvarchar(MAX);

SET @fx_rates_json = N'{
    "date": "2019-12-02",
    "quotes": {
        "USDAED": 3.673197,
        "USDAFN": 78.79768,
        "USDALL": 110.795056
    }
}';

SELECT payload.date,
       V.Currency,
       V.value
FROM OPENJSON(@fx_rates_json)
         WITH ([date] date,
               quotes nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) payload
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(payload.quotes)
                     WITH(AED float N'$.USDAED',
                          AFN float N'$.USDAFN',
                          [ALL] float N'$.USDALL') quotes
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('ARS',quotes.AED),
                        ('AUG',quotes.AFN),
                        ('BGN',quotes.[ALL])) V(Currency,value);
```